# remove rows with duplicated values of two columns that are shifted in pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['1044', '1924'], ['1044', '1926'], ['1044', '1927'], ['1044', '1928'], ['1048', '1924'], ['1048', '1926'], ['1048', '1927'], ['1048', '1928'], ['1051', '1924'], ['1051', '1926'], ['1051', '1927'], ['1051', '1928'], ['1058', '']]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

[image]

I would like to reduce the dataframe as shown here:

[image]

I have no clue how to do that, but it should be working as follows:

- keep the first duplicate in the column "Date" - in this example row 0
- drop the second duplicate in the column "Value" - in this example row 3

Hopefully it does exist a easier way how to perform it.

Comment: You could build a new dataframe: ``pd.DataFrame({key:pd.unique(value) for key, value in df.items()})``

Comment: works perfect. Thank you. How can i define these two columns in the code above?

Comment: @sammywemmy smart one, you should post it as answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can build a new dataframe instead, with the unique values:

```py
pd.DataFrame({key:pd.unique(value) for key, value in df.items()})
Out[252]: 
   Col1  Col2
0  1044  1924
1  1048  1926
2  1051  1927
```

Comment: Thanky you once more. In the real dataset there are several columns. How could i set those two columns for the operation?

Comment: Note that this works in this specific case where the columns are "product-like" in order, this is not necessarily the case if the order is not consistent ;)

Comment: You can filter for the specific columns: ``pd.DataFrame({key:pd.unique(value) for key, value in df.filter([l'Col1', 'Col2']).items()})``

Comment: yea, just as @mozway noted, if the order is not consistent, this wont work

Comment: yea, this is right. It also does not work with NaNs.

Comment: you can add more data, with more columns. I'm sure someone can come up with something more robust

Comment: done. Sorry, i did not expect that could have an influence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method that should work irrespective of the order, with an arbitrary number of columns, and which should be easy to customize if more complex selections are needed:

```
(df.assign(x=df.groupby('Col1').ngroup(),
           y=df.groupby('Col1').cumcount())
  .query('x==y') # this can be updated in case more complex selections are required
  .drop(['x','y'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2
0  1044  1924
4  1048  1926
8  1051  1927
```

##### edit: method for non "product-like" data

```
df.assign(x=df.groupby('Col1', dropna=False).ngroup(),
          y=df.groupby('Col1', dropna=False).cumcount())
  .query('x>=y')
  .drop_duplicates('Col1', keep='last')
  .drop(['x','y'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    Col1  Col2
0   1044  1924
5   1048  1926
10  1051  1927
12  1058
```

*NB. I saved `x` and `y` as intermediate columns here to be able to see how it works and to debug, but you can also use those operations directly for slicing*

```
(df[df.groupby('Col1', dropna=False).ngroup().ge(
    df.groupby('Col1', dropna=False).cumcount())]
  .drop_duplicates('Col1', keep='last')
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to modify the df. It would be perfect, when also a row with missing value would be in the output df. If not, i could save all rows with NaN to the separate df and then append them with the result.

Comment: @Parsyk that's what I alluded to in my original answer. You need to change the condition for filtering, see the update.

Answer (score 1):

I think, cumcount each column and check similarities between the outputs, Code below;

```
df =df.assign(Date_cumcount=df.groupby('Date').cumcount(),Value_cumcount = df.groupby('Value').cumcount())
out =df[df['Date_cumcount']==df['Value_cumcount']].drop(['Date_cumcount','Value_cumcount'],1)



     Date Value
0   1044  1924
5   1048  1926
10  1051  1927
12  1058
```